# ZF2 Getting selected value from DateSelect Element

Tags: php, forms, zend-framework, element

In my application I use the DateSelect element to receive the users birthday. When I test the form by selecting the birthday values my field stays empty as it supposed to give me back a date format.

My form code;

```
$this->add(array(
            'name' => 'date_of_birth',
            'type' => 'DateSelect',
            'options' => array(
                'create_empty_option' => true,
                'max_year'            => date('Y') - 12,
                'day_attributes'      => array(
                    'data-placeholder' => 'Day',
                    'style'            => 'width: 31.5%',
                ),
                'month_attributes'    => array(
                    'data-placeholder' => 'Month',
                    'style'            => 'width: 31.5%',
                ),
                'year_attributes'     => array(
                    'data-placeholder' => 'Year',
                    'style'            => 'width: 31.5%',
                )
            ),
        ));
```

Getting the form elements in my view:

```
<?php echo $this->formRow($form->get('date_of_birth')); ?>
```

And test output in my controller:

```
..
Debug::dump($_POST);

.....
Debug::dump($form->getData());
```

$_POST returns;

```
 ....
 'day' => string '06' (length=2)
 'month' => string '05' (length=2)
 'year' => string '1999' (length=4)
 ...
```

But $form->getData() returns;

```
 ....
 'date_of_birth' => null
 ....
```

It supposed to give me a date_of_birth filled with a date as far as I read on internet ([blog](http://www.michaelgallego.fr/blog/2012/11/09/discover-whats-coming-for-zendform-in-zf-2-1/)). What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

By now I use a workaround as given below, if someone figured out how to manage it in the right way, please let me know!

```
$aPostData = $request->getPost();
  if ($request->getPost('year') && $request->getPost('month') && $request->getPost('day')) {
    $dateTimeFormat = new \DateTime(date('Y-m-d', strtotime($request->getPost('year') . '-' . $request->getPost('month') . '-' . $request->getPost('day'))));
    $aPostData['date_of_birth'] = $dateTimeFormat->format('Y-m-d');
  }
$form->setData($aPostData);
```